# Symfony 4 Dynamic Subdomain Routing and Nginx Config

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, symfony4

I want to handle dynamic subdomain in my Symfony 4 application.

I'm looking for configuration like this:

- store1.domain.com => StoreController::index
- store2.domain.com => StoreController::index
- www.domain.com => HomeController::homePage
- domain.com => HomeController::homePage *etc etc.*

I'm trying this code but is not working. Its always match with HomeController. StoreController never matching.

And when I try this configuration "domain.com" request show to me "Welcome to nginx!" page.

```
class StoreController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="store_home", host="{store_name}.domain.test")
     */
    public function storeHomepage()
    {
        return $this->render('store/index.html.twig');
    }
}

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="site_home")
     */
    public function homePage()
    {
        return $this->render('site/home/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.test;
    root       /site/root/public;

    location config bla bla bla;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying this code but is not working. Its always match with
>   HomeController. StoreController never matching.

You are using annotation routing, so the routes are loaded alphabetically.

Your home controller will be tried first, and it will match, because you have not put any restrictions on it.

Try explicitly setting the host.

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="site_home", host="domain.test")
     */
    public function homePage()
    {
        return $this->render('site/home/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

> And when I try this configuration "domain.com" request show to me
>   "Welcome to nginx!" page.

I'm not really an nginx expert, but I believe that `server_name  *.domain.test;` means all subdomains, but exludes the main domain. Try it as `server_name  .domain.test;`

Comment: Working for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In NGINX configuration you can specify multiple server_name like : 
 server_name  example.org  www.example.org;

That should work for you :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.test domain.test;
    root       /site/root/public;

    location config bla bla bla;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html